# Using Javascript to change style according to current selections

Tags: javascript, styles

Here is my Javascript code that I am running when head element changes:

```
function updateStyle() {
    var head = document.getElementById("Heads").src;
    pos = head.indexOf("/Heads/");
    namePart = head.substring((pos + 7), (pos + 7 + 6))
    namePart = namePart.replace('.', '');

    switch (namePart) {
        case "Head2":
            document.getElementById("EarsX").style.top = "35em"
            document.getElementById("EarsX").style.transform = "25deg"
            document.getElementById("EarsY").style.top = "35em"
            document.getElementById("EarsY").style.left = "82em"
            document.getElementById("EarsY").style.transform = "-25deg"
            console.log("updated Ears")
    }
    location.reload();
}
```

I get the "updated Ears" in the console but EarsY still looks like this:

```
#EarsY {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45em;
    left: 85em;`enter code here`
}
```

That's from Chrome developer tools.

I tried adding a class before this, but it didn't work either.

Comment: Did you check the styling on the actual object? Or is that CSS you're showing from a CSS stylesheet? Because your code would change the `style` attribute on the actual element, not alter the stylesheets.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want.  I want the element changed, not the style sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try not adding `.src` in the end  of this
`var head = document.getElementById("Heads").src;`

Comment: code now:    

var head = document.getElementById("Heads");
    pos = head.src.indexOf("/Heads/");
    namePart = head.src.substring((pos + 7), (pos + 7 + 6))
    namePart = namePart.replace('.', '');

Comment: same issue.  No change.  ("EarsX").style.top is still the original value, nothing has changed.

Comment: I have to use .src to get the name of the file associated with Heads.

Comment: If I could get anything to work with using Javascript to dynamically change layout I would be happy.